# Quiero encoger y agrandar mi QPushButton, pero no se encoge después de agrandarlo con QPropertyAnimation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyside2

Quiero que al darle yo clic al boton, haga mas grande, y de hecho lo hace, pero tambien quiero que despues de darle clic y ya este grande, se encoja al tamaño original, esto lo hago llamando a la funcion `animate_button`, pero no lo encoge despues de agrandarlo.

El archivo interactua con el archivo principal el cual es `self.iu`, pero el boton con el que estoy trabajando es independiente, lo hice desde el codigo.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
import PyQt5.QtWidgets as wid
import sys, gui


class MainApp(wid.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainApp, self).__init__()
        self.ui = gui.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)     
        # Creating a ico from coding in a python file, we can select the icon path       
        self.pushButton = wid.QPushButton(self.ui.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setText('Click Here!')
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120,140,80,50))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet('background-color: black; color: white; border-radius: 15px;')
```

El boton aparece con un icono pero puedes quitarlo para no tener problemas

```
        # Two differentes ways to create the icon of button
        image = QPixmap('./Icons/cil-3d.png')
        #self.pushButton.setIcon(QIcon('./Icons/cil-3d.png'))
        self.pushButton.setIcon(QIcon(image))

        self.pushButton.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(20,20))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.animate_button)
```

Aqui esta la funcion que se encarga de animar le boton, primero comprueba que el anchor del boton sea 80, si lo es, lo incrementara a 140, sino lo volveria a poner en 80, pero no funciona esta segunda parte.

```
    def animate_button(self):
        width = self.pushButton.width()
        if width == 80:
            n_width = 140
        else:
            n_width = 80
        print(f'Width = {width} and n_width = {n_width}')
        self.animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.pushButton, b'minimumWidth')
        self.animation.setDuration(250)
        self.animation.setStartValue(width)
        self.animation.setEndValue(n_width)
        self.animation.setEasingCurve(QtCore.QEasingCurve.InOutQuart)
        self.animation.start()
        print('Started!')
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wid.QApplication(sys.argv)
    application = MainApp()
    application.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 1):

Pude solucionarlo, simplemente cambiando otra propiedad que hace exactamente lo mismo, cambie la propiedad `geometry`, en vez de `minimumWidth`, de esa manera ya se encoge y agranda cada vez que le doy al boton.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
import PyQt5.QtWidgets as wid
import sys, gui


class MainApp(wid.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainApp, self).__init__()
        self.ui = gui.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)     
        # Creating a ico from coding in a python file, we can select the icon path      
        self.pushButton = wid.QPushButton(self.ui.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setText('Click Here!')
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120,140,80,50))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet('background-color: black; color: white; border-radius: 15px;')

        # Two differentes ways to create the icon of button
        image = QPixmap('./Icons/cil-3d.png')
        #self.pushButton.setIcon(QIcon('./Icons/cil-3d.png'))
        self.pushButton.setIcon(QIcon(image))

        self.pushButton.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(20,20))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.animate_button)
        

    def animate_button(self):
        width = self.pushButton.width()
        if width == 80:
            n_width = 140
        else:
            n_width = 80
        print(f'Width = {width} and n_width = {n_width}')
        self.animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.pushButton, b'geometry')
        self.animation.setDuration(250)
        # Si funciona con esto
        self.animation.setStartValue(QtCore.QRect(120,140,width,50))
        self.animation.setEndValue(QtCore.QRect(120,140,n_width,50))
        self.animation.setEasingCurve(QtCore.QEasingCurve.InOutQuart)
        self.animation.start()
        print('Started!')
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wid.QApplication(sys.argv)
    application = MainApp()
    application.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: Despues de dar clic en la imagen]
[image: Regresa a la forma original despues de dar clic]